# Just how realistic are the bounds in Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions

I was reading about Chebyshev's Inequality

$$
P(|X-\mu|>k \sigma)<\frac{1}{k^2}
$$

and the following came to mind: We know that it is rather conservative. It's a crude estimate for all the common probability distributions. My question is can we find a distribution for which the inequality is strict ? Or perhaps to within a constant factor ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235548

Comment: Or see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was looking for..